# Python Member Counter

Tags: python

**I tried This but didn't work**

```
def CountMember(s):
lowercaseletter = ["e", "f", "g", "h", "y", "j"]
upperrcaseletter = ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X"]
numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Yo = ["!", ",", "\\"]

if s == Yo or lowercaseletter or upperrcaseletter or numbers:
    for i in range (len(s)):
        if s[i:i+3] == "e"  "f" "g" "h" "y" "j""F""G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X"  "!" "," "\\":
            CountMember +=1
else:
    print(0)
s='ee'
print(CountMember)
CountMember()
```

**This is the image 2.4 question will explain it**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpY2j.png

Comment: All relevant information has to be included as text in your post, not external images of text.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpY2j.png this is the image link

Comment: This code has lots of basic errors.  We can't even tell what you're trying to do!

Comment: I wnat to check if one of this characters in the lists are given as S and count them as numbers

Comment: @SanadAbdullah you misunderstood, you're _not_ supposed to include an image of text, you should include the text _itself_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def CountMember(s):
    lowercaseletter = ["e", "f", "g", "h", "y", "j"]
    upperrcaseletter = ["F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X"]
    numbers = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    Yo = ["!", ",", "\\"]
    total = lowercaseletter + upperrcaseletter + numbers + Yo
    CountMembr = len([i for i in s if i in total])
    print(CountMembr)

CountMember('keep a value of s here')
```

This shall help

Comment: No value for argument 's' in function call

Comment: Thank You For Helping